# Would caves maintain a cool temperature in a climate with very hot days and cold nights?

Tags: caves

If the surface temperature is 60°C in the day and -40°C at night, with an average of 10°C all year, would the caves maintain a stable temperature?

Comment: Asking two very similar questions within a few hours of each other is slightly irritating. Consider waiting long enough to get some decent answers and feedback on your first question before moving on. Remember that stackexchange sites tend to be international, and waiting 24-48 hours gives everyone a good chance to see your question and maybe even respond.

Answer (score 2):

### Mostly yes.

The main thing determining temperature is the geothermal capacity of the rock, which is mostly constant year round. The average temperature is the main thing fixing their temperature.

The mouth of the cave can have some temperature variance, caves with multiple openings can have convection currents which can sharply vary the temperature, and very deep caves with access to the higher temperatures deep down can be different.

Caves with multiple entrances is the main problematic thing for colonization. You can block off exits, but it would be a substantial amount of work for some new caves.

Answer (score 1):

In short yes, there will be a big difference in temperature. However, the amount of difference between the temperature outside the cave and inside will depend on how deep the cave is and if there is anything in the cave that might impact how warm it is. For example, if it is an old volcanic lava tube, it might be warm because of nearby lava, and similarly if there is a cold underground river it could cool it down.